# In python why is list[i:i] = [n] insert an element in list[i:i]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Why do python have this behavior ? how can it be explained ?

```
mylist=[5, 9, 13, 15, 16]
n=14
i=0
mylist[i:i] = [n]
print(mylist)


Output:
[14, 5, 9, 13, 15, 16]
```

Comment: It's pretty much just how slice assignment is defined. Are you asking *why* it's defined this way? Did you expect `mylist[i:i] = [n]` to do something different?

Comment: Where can I find the documentation about slice assignment ? 
I read it is like a mylist.__setitem(slice(i,i), [n]).

I would also like to know if it is inplace or does it need a copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#mutable-sequence-types)**,

> s[ i : j ] = t --> slice of s from i to j is *replaced* by the contents of the iterable t
>
> s.append(x) --> appends x to the end of the sequence (same as s[len(s):len(s)] = [x])
>
> s.insert(i, x)  --> inserts `x` into `s` at the index given by i (same as s[i:i] = [x])

`s[i:i] = [x]` behaves like `insert` and `s[len(s):len(s)] = [x]` behaves like `append`.

Let's examine `s[i:j] = [t]`,

**1.** If `i == j`, then it will behave like `insert` and *inserts* `t`'s content to `s` in index `j`

**2.** If `i == j == len(s)`, then it will behave like `append` and *appends* `t`'s content to `s`.

**3.** If `i != j` then slice of s from `i` to `j` is *replaced* by the contents of the iterable `t`.

Your question is case 1. It will behave like *insert* and 14 will be inserted position 0.

**Case 3 Example**

```
a = [5, 15, 13, 8, 16]
t = [4,2]
a[1:3] = t
print(a)  # [5, 4, 2, 8, 16]
```

What it really happens that slice of 1 to 3 (15 and 13) has replaced by contents of `t`.

Comment: So it should replace the element from 0 to 0 with [14]. That makes sense. Although I am asking it to replace an element that should not exist. 

I would also like to know if it is inplace or does it need a copy ?

Comment: I have added clarity. Also it is inplace.

Comment: What's its complexity, although it is in place it shifts all the element right to i ?

Answer (score 2):

Python [documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) slice assignment as follows:

> `s[i:j] = t` - slice of *s* from *i* to *j* is replaced by the contents of the iterable *t*

From this definition it follows that assigning `[14]` to `mymlist[0:0]`, as in the question, *replaces* the previous content of `mylist[0:0]` (an empty list) with the provided single-element list, `[14]`.

The replacement consists of deleting the old contents (no-op, since the contents of `[i:i]` is empty for any `i`) and inserting the new contents, which may be observed by `14` being the new beginning element of the list.

Comment: It is an insertion, like mylist.insert ?

Comment: @SanhajiOmar It is a **replacement**, deletion followed by insertion. Since in your case you replace an empty slice, you only see the insertion. `mylist.insert` can only insert, and only a single element; slice assignment can replace any number of elements with any number of elements.